# Bootstrap dropdown inside button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in the middle of my page. I followed the guide to center it, but the dropdown menu keeps being placed in the button.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" id="timezoneDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false">
        What timezone are you in?
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="timezoneDropdown">
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">GMT</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">UTC</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">ECT</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">EET</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">ART</button></li>
        <li><button class="dropdown-item">EAT</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the css too? and which guide you used

Comment: Its bootstrap, so the guide would be https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Is there only going to be one button in your button group?

Comment: Yes, there is only one button to bring down the dropdown

Comment: And you want the button centered? Or the buttons in the dropdown centered?

Comment: I want the dropdown to be under the button, but it is inside of it

Comment: You must have other styles affecting it, your code as provided with just bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js works exactly as expected (https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/yk0zsd67/). Nothing is centered and the docs page ("guide") to which you refer, mentions nothing about centering anything. Your problem is neither clear nor reproducible.

Comment: which bootstrapversion you are use?

Comment: And you need include the Javascript file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code and it works perfectly as a drop down menu entirely as it should. I added a wrapper around the *btn-group* to get the centering that you mentioned.....

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" id="timezoneDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
            What timezone are you in?
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="timezoneDropdown">
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">GMT</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">UTC</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">ECT</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">EET</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">ART</button></li>
            <li><button class="dropdown-item">EAT</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```